# Drop down arrow gravity forms

Tags: css, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Hi I have a form on this current site: http://bombyx-plm.flywheelsites.com/#contact

I wish to have drop down arrows on the two drop down fields: "Company size" & "Select subject" as you can see I have added images before the place holders. using "background: url" but in doing so I have lost the drop down arrows...

Is there anyway to have the drop down arrows with the image in the same place holder box?

Hope you can help!

Thanks

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Look at this  https://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/VYMeXp

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the responses! Sudharshan Nair had the answer I needed to create the drop down arrow.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly, you wish to add the drop-down arrow as a png arrow in the background without losing the other background image.

You should use the multi-background CSS code as in the link below:

https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_backgrounds.asp